# SQL get last record of group where

Tags: sql

my table is the following:

```
Id   Timestamp            name_id     testobject_id 
----------------------------------------------------
2  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 1        |  1
3  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 2        |  1
1  | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 1        |  1
4  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 1        |  2
5  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 2        |  2
```

I want the last record of each group (name_id). But i only want the results where testobject_id = 1

But this doesnt seem to work. I am thankful for every help.

```
SELECT *
    FROM checkresult
    WHERE timestamp IN (
        SELECT MAX(timestamp)
        FROM checkresult
        WHERE test_object_id = 1    
        GROUP BY name_id
    );
```

Desired Output:

```
Id   Timestamp            name_id     testobject_id 
----------------------------------------------------
2  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 1        |  1
3  | 2017-12-15 18:36:46 | 2        |  1
```

Comment: and which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `where` only in the outermost query:

```
SELECT cr.*
FROM checkresult cr
WHERE cr.test_object_id = 1 AND
      cr.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(cr2.timestamp)
                      FROM checkresult cr2
                      WHERE cr2.name_id = cr.name_id
                     );
```

Notice the change to using a correlated subquery.  This is important, because rows for different names could have the same timestamp value.  What is latest for one name may not be latest for another.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM checkresult r
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT name_id, MAX(timestamp)
        FROM checkresult
        WHERE test_object_id = 1    
        GROUP BY name_id
    ) g ON r. name_id = g.name_id 
       and r.timestamp = g.timestamp
WHERE r.test_object_id = 1
```

Comment: @RadimBača thanks, yes, & I prefer the inner join over a correlation

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    Id
    , Timestamp
    , name_id
    , test_object_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Id
            , Timestamp
            , name_id
            , test_object_id
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name_id ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) R
        FROM checkresult
        WHERE test_object_id = 1
    ) Q
WHERE R = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.*
from checkresult c
where c.timestamp = (
       select max(timestamp) from checkresult where name_id = c.name_id
   )
group by c.name_id
```